# Binary outcome prediction with binary data

Tags: r, statistics

I am new to R programming and have searched through stackoverflow, but couldn't find a similar topic, although it has to be somewhere. So a link to a similar case would be sufficient.

I have a data set of 110 cases and about 50 variables. Most of the variables are binary, some categorical or numeric. All of them could be made binary if needed. The 50 variables  represents factors in written reports that should predict the decision if an action is taken (1) or not (0).

I want to perform a retrospective study and see which variables were the key factors in decision making. I have performed a pearson chi square test on every single variable and only 2 correlate significantly with action or not. Now I want to calculate which combination of variables were needed for an action. I only don't know which test I have to perform for this.

Anyone has an idea how to test this in R

Comment: This is not a specific programming question. If you need help choosing an appropriate statistical model to analyze your data, you should be asking over at [stats.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will go to Cross Validated